# Oxygen Sensor Engine Light

Tags: o2-sensor, obd

I had Oxygen Sensor Engine Light that complained about the Bank 1 Sensor 1. I used my OBD2 tool to clear the code, and the engine light is not coming back.

Can I leave the sensor as is or still I should replace it since I had the OBD engine code at least once?

**Update after a week**

The engine light came back. Lesson learned: Once you see the code, the sensor needs to be changed.

**Final update**

I replaced the sensor and the engine light is gone for good.

Comment: How long has it been since you cleared the code? Do you know that the system is reporting in a ready status?

Comment: @dwizum, I cleared the code 24 hours ago, but I did not do any intensive driving. How many miles should I drive untill I know the initial code was a false alert?

Comment: @Allan Xu Depending on your car manufacturer's smog tests and your driving patterns I've seen oxygen sensor tests clear up in 2-3 days of normal driving.

Comment: I've also seen CELs come back after 2-3 days of normal driving. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a code came up and you cleared it without fixing it, it will come back. Once you clear a code, the computer resets the Readiness monitors and start to conduct a new drive cycle test routine. Since you didn't fix the problem, it will probably fail the drive cycle and light the light again with the same code. Read [this post](http://ricksfreeautorepairadvice.com/readiness-monitors-and-drive-cycles/) on drive cycles and readiness monitors

Answer (score 2):

It could also be a one time anomaly.  If it were me I would wait to see if it comes back a second time since you already cleared the code.  If not, I wouldn't worry about it.  If it comes back, time to fix it.